# Load all posts and check if the post is liked or not in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a `Post` model and a `Like` model.

When I go a user page, I can see all the posts he liked. Now, I want to indicate a small icon if a post is already liked by the logged in user who is visiting a user page.

This is how I select the liked posts of the user (not the logged user but the profile owner):

```
$likesPost = Post::with('user')->join('likes', function ($join) use ($user) {
    $join->on('likes.likeable_id', '=', 'id')->where('likes.user_id', '=', $user->id)->where('likes.likeable_type','=', Post::class);
})->get();
```

Now I want to also check if the authenticated user has already liked this post or not along with this query. I've tried many things but I'm not sure how I should approach this problem. I'm using polymorphic relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would change up your initial query a little bit. I'd get the posts liked by the user like this (assuming the `Post` has a `likes` relationship):

```
$profileLikedPosts = Post::whereHas('likes', function($query) use ($user) {
        return $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Next, you can get the liked posts of the currently logged in user like this:

```
// The "whereIn" just limits the results to those posts already retrieved
// for the profile user. Not required, but gives a little performance boost
// if this collection doesn't need the non-profile-liked posts.

$authUser = Auth::user();
$authLikedPosts = Post::whereHas('likes', function($query) use ($authUser) {
        return $query->where('user_id', $authUser->id);
    })
    ->whereIn('id', $profileLikedPosts->lists('id'))
    ->get();
```

Now, in your blade template, as you loop through the liked posts for the profile user (`$profileLikedPosts`), you can use the Collection `contains()` method to check if the post was also liked by the logged in user:

```
@foreach ($profileLikedPosts as $post)
    // ...
    @if ($authLikedPosts->contains('id', $post->id))
        // this post is liked by both; show your icon
    @endif
    // ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$user->posts()` this only collects the posts that the user created. Right? I want to check it in all the posts.

Comment: @user1012181 Yes, that's correct. Re-reading your question, that makes sense. So, you can just change `$user->posts()->` to `Post::`. (same for `$authUser->posts()->`)

Comment: Thanks. It helped. But the `$authLikedPosts->has($post->id)` should be 
`$authLikedPosts->contains('id', $post->id)`

Comment: @user1012181 Yep, you're correct. I had though that Eloquent Collections were automatically keyed by the model ids, but that isn't so. In that case, yes, `contains()` is the correct method to use. For Eloquent Collections, if you only pass in the value, it will automatically look up the key field on the model and compare that, but it is probably safer to specify the field in case you call a method that turns your Eloquent Collection into a Base Collection.